Mock in Spring Boot
Why is it necessary to use @Mock in spring boot testing when you can inject dependencies directly into the test class and it still works?
I tried using the above 2 ways and both work, so how are they different, when to use @Mock and when to inject dependency

Use @Mock when you want to isolate the unit under test and control the behavior of its dependencies.
Use direct dependency injection (@Autowired or constructor injection) when you want to test the actual behavior of your class with its real dependencies in an integration test.

If you can use your real dependencies, go ahead and use them. But sometimes you can't or wouldn't want to, e.g. a dependency which calls external systems such as a database or a webservice. You would then replace those dependencies with test doubles. In a Spring Boot test, these are usually annotated with @MockBean, not @Mock (@Mock is for Mockito-based tests)

"Why is it necessary to use @Mock" - it isn't. Unless you want Mock something. Don't believe anything that ChatGPT tells you, it is not intelligent.

@Gimby not only ChatGPT, I know lots of devs who will tell you to use @Mock heavily. A test without 10+ @Mock fields is not a good test.

Think about what you want to test.
In Mockito for example you can control what some mock method returns without extra knowledge of this method internal behaviour. Just kind of isolation. So you can test your method with edge cases and expect what mock returns. For example you can declare that mocked object method returns the following:

Empty List
Null
Multiple Objects

With the help of mockes you can manipulate how the data flows during your test. That is quite convinient. You can't do such things with real objects.
What is more - you can verify how much mocked object method was called. This feature is also quite useful.
Mock everything other than method/class that you are testing.
